# Trying to understand when a groupby object is created and when a non-grouped object is created

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe calles 'dft' containing details of various Netflix TV shows and Movies, from which I extract that subset where the country is either India or Spain. This subset is then grouped by country, and I extract the column "listed_in", which contains genre categories for the TV show/ Movie of each row.

```
dft[(dft['country']=='India') | (dft['country'] == 'Spain')].groupby('country')['listed_in']
```

Now this is a groupby object:

```
pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x7fce4b821ac0
```

Now, I check how many of these have the category "Documentary" as one of the genres.

```
dft[(dft['country']=='India') | (dft['country'] == 'Spain')].groupby('country')['listed_in'].apply(
    lambda x: x.str.contains('Documentaries'))
```

```
Out[8]: 
4      False
24     False
39     False
50     False
66     False
69     False
105    False
109    False
114    False
116    False
Name: listed_in, dtype: bool
```

Now this is a routine non-groupby series where its just a list of boolean results on the whole "listed_in" column without slicing by country.

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

But then if I ask for `value_counts()` or  `sum()`  inside the apply function, the result is presented differently.

```
dft[(dft['country']=='India') | (dft['country'] == 'Spain')].groupby('country')['listed_in'].apply(
    lambda x: x.str.contains('Documentaries').sum())
```

```
country
India    19
Spain    17
Name: listed_in, dtype: int64
```

Now this is also being shown as a non-groupby Series, however I am wondering why is it that just applying the `string.contains()` filter gives a series presented without country differentiation. If I add a `.sum()` outside the apply function bracket like this:

```
dft[(dft['country']=='India') | (dft['country'] == 'Spain')].groupby('country')['listed_in'].apply(
    lambda x: x.str.contains('Documentaries')).sum()
```

I get 36, the total number of True values across both India and Spain. But when I apply `sum()` or `value_counts()` inside the apply bracket I get a result that is separated for India (19) and Spain (17) as shown above.

I am trying to understand why this is so. Why doesn't just applying the `str.contains()` produce a series of boolean value differentiated by country? And if it doesn't, what difference does adding the ````sum()``` make.  Should that prove above my station right now, I at least want to understand when this happens so I can keep that in mind for data analysis.

Comment: In the 2 cases, you `apply` a function to each group but `str.contains` returns a boolean for each row inside the group rather than `sum` aggregates all rows of your group so the output cannot be the same.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: That the series of boolean values given by checking the 'Documentaries' condition is also differentiated based on Spain and India. So it would look something like Spain: A list of corresponding boolean results, Then India: A list of corresponding boolean results. Basically that the checking of the condition whether 'Documentaries' is present in is done and presented separately for India and for Spain, as is the case when the sum of the results is asked for using ```.sum()``` inside the apply function.